# How to add modprobe command to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, modprobe

Ubuntu 20.04
To make my WiFi happy I enter the following modprobe via the terminal;
`modprobe -r brcmfmac`
Then wait 5 seconds and `modprobe brcmfmac`
**Can I add this to a startup process so that I don't have to manually execute it each time?**
I have tried adding it to my GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT but after I grub-update and reboot my wireless still hangs untill I manually enter the commands as aboove.
Is my syntax wrong? Can someone advise the proper way to add it?
Or should I not be adding this to the boot image?
I get the same result when I boot to my fallback 5.4.0-40 kernel image.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, kernel 5.7 is not a supported Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: I have also tried adding an **rc.local file** but this did not fix it either. It did execute as evident in the `dmesg` output but after loggin in the wireless was still hung and required manually entering the modprobe in a terminal. I reckon there must be a way to do it in the grub file, so I am hoping someone has ideas.